# footnotemark misbehaves in titles, minipages, beamer frametitles

Tags: beamer, footnotes, titles, minipage, frame-title

In titles or in `minipage` texts, `\footnotemark` puts the marks correctly, but the `\footnotetext` misbehaves: if the `\footnotemark` is used in `\title`, the corresponding `\footnotetext` always gets the 0 counter in the bottom of the page.  In case of a `minipage`, `\footnotetext` gets nothing.  I noticed the problem when I used `beamer` and I put `\footnotemark` in the `\frametitle`.  There was no other text in the frame, only pictures, and I had to put the explanation for the title somewhere. Here is an example, showing both the problem with `\title` and `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7cm, paperheight=10cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\title{Test\footnotemark\,\, and\footnotemark{}} \date{}
\maketitle


\footnotetext{1st gets 0 but marked with *}
\footnotetext{2nd also gets 0 but marked with $\dagger$}


\fbox{
  \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
    mini\footnotemark{} page\footnotemark{}

  \footnotetext{in minipage 1st gets nohing}
  \footnotetext{in minipage 2nd also gets nothing}
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: footmarks in minipage and titles]

The following example is very close to the original problem I had in beamer.  In fact, in the original case, I reset the footnote mark for every frame---unlike here.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% I do like * as footnotemark in titles 
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Our World\footnotemark}

  \includegraphics{earth.jpg}

  \footnotetext{Meaning, the Earth, since ... (long explanation not
    related to the main topic of the lecture).}
\end{frame}
```

[image: beamer example]

Comment: This is by design of LaTeX. Minipages have their own footnote counter, `mpfootnote`, but `footnotemark` does not use it, unfortunately. Use `footmisc` package and `\mpfootnotemark`, for example and `\maketitle` redefines `\thefootnote`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the beamer example, you can workaround the problem like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% I do like * as footnotemark in titles 
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Our World\footnotemark[1]}

  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image}

    \addtocounter{footnote}{1}
  \footnotetext{Meaning, the Earth, since ... (long explanation not
    related to the main topic of the lecture).}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]